# using different version of package within python anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I see that I have both version of tensorflow in anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages:

- tensorflow-1.14.0.dist-info/
- tensorflow-2.1.0.dist-info/

But when I start anaconda2/bin/jupyter qtconsole, I always get 1.14. How do I use 2.1?

The history may be something like this:

1. 1.14 comes with conda
2. I did pip install for 2.1
3. I tried to do "pip install tensorflow-datasets', it didn't work.
4. Googling suggested "conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-datasets". It looks this set tensorflow back to 1.14
5. I tried different ways of 'pip install' 'conda install' 'conda update', but can't get tensorflow to 2.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Uninstall tensorflow , and then try to import it . What does it show?

Comment: uninstall tensorflow 1.14 using conda? 2.1 is probably installed by pip and not known to conda somehow.

Comment: uninstall tensorflow 1.14 using 'conda reomove' won't solve the issue, after uninstalling, install using 'pip install' gives error: WARNING: No metadata found in /nfs/gearrundata/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_pasta-0.2.0.dist-info/METADATA'

Answer (score 0):

anaconda 2 can't install tensorflow 2.x using conda install, I had to re-install anaconda 2, then install tf 2.x using pip install